# Convert string to a list of strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure where I will use `@variable` in

```
WHERE colname LIKE(@variable)
```

This `@variable` could be a string list representing column names, such as

```
EXEC usp_cols 'col1, col2, col3';
```

I want to split this string to list of strings in the stored procedure, so that it converts to `'col1', 'col2', 'col3'` in the stored procedure to use it in the LIKE statement:

```
WHERE colname LIKE('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
```

Comment: In SQL 2016 and later versions you could use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: How about a table variable or a table-valued parameter

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What query would you do with the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest version.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = 'COL1  , COL2   , COL3'
    , @separator CHAR(2) = ', '
    , @quote CHAR(1) = CHAR(39)
    , @output VARCHAR(500);

-- Method #1
SET @output = @quote + REPLACE(@input,  @separator, CONCAT(@quote,',', @quote)) + @quote;

SELECT  @output;

/*
Separator could be ',' or ', ' (with space after the coma), ' , ' (or space before and after)
*/
-- Method #2, SQL Server 2017 onwards
SELECT @output = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(@quote, TRIM(value), @quote), ',')
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input, ',');

SELECT @output;
```

Comment: Separator could be ',' or ', ' (with space after the coma), ' , ' (or space before and after). I cannot guarantee that the person using the stored procedure will enter the data in the format I want. So I need to make sure there is no space in column names.

Comment: @Yana, I updated the answer with Method #2. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

As mention in comment, from 2016 you can use STRING_SPLIT. Read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

It is as simple to use as this:

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet.', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE VARCHAR(100);
SET @VARIABLE='COL1,COL2,COL3';
DECLARE @DELIMITER CHAR(1)=',';
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@VARIABLE,@DELIMITER);

--EXAMPLE
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T',N'U')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tempdb..#T;
CREATE TABLE #T
(
   ID TINYINT NOT NULL,
   SURNAME VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT #T(ID,SURNAME)VALUES(1,'IVAN'),(2,'JOHN'),(3,'PETER'),(4,'PAUL')

DECLARE @InSearchValues VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @InDelimeter CHAR(1);

SET @InDelimeter=',';
SET @InSearchValues='PETER,PAUL,IV%';


SELECT T.ID,T.SURNAME
FROM #T AS T
CROSS APPLY
 (
    SELECT X.value FROM string_split(@InSearchValues,@InDelimeter)AS X
    WHERE T.SURNAME LIKE X.value
 )R

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer with an example that shows `WHERE colname LIKE` to answer the question.

Comment: What if I have space after ', '?

Comment: Also, I need it not as a separate rows but as a list of strings, so I can ass it to the WHERE... LIKE ('col1', 'col2', 'col3') clause

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from the community, I think I have the result that I wanted:

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE VARCHAR(100);
SET @VARIABLE='COL1, COL2, COL3';

DECLARE @DELIMITER CHAR(1)=',';
DECLARE @variable2 varchar(500)

SELECT VALUE
INTO #columnNames
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@VARIABLE,@DELIMITER)

SELECT@variable2 = coalesce(@variable2 + ',', '') + convert(varchar(500), '''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) + '''') from #columnNames

PRINT@variable2
```

Now I get the following result which can be implemented in WHERE... LIKE clause:

```
'COL1','COL2','COL3'
```

Comment: What would `@variable2` do in this case? You would only have a single result from the temp table

Comment: The result from the temp table is a column, I need it in the format that I show above. This is why I use @variable.

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted to *split* the values to use in a join, not re-aggregate them. Any case, that style of code (aggregating into a variable) is unsafe in the face of parallelism and should not be used to aggregate. Use `STRING_AGG` instead.

Comment: Could you please write the code using STRING_AGG because I am not confident I can use it properly?

Comment: @Yana, I updated the answer with Method #2. Check it out.